# using 3rd party libraries with angular-cli (angular2) projects

Tags: angular, npm, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a project which was scaffolded using angular-cli. There is no system.config file. I've used the angular-cli [github documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation) to install underscore:

```
npm install underscore --save
```

src/typings.d.ts

```
declare module 'underscore';
```

src/app/full-table.component.ts

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';
_.method();
```

When I try to use underscore (e.g _.findwhere) I get the console error:

```
__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_underscore__.findWhere is not a function
```

If I throw in a debugger right beneath the import statement and type '_' into the console, I get the underscore object returned

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please, make sure you've added javascript dist file to angular-cli.json in 'scripts' object.

And if you've imported it as _, then you must use it like _.somefuncion() to get imported function.

Comment: I have done both of the above and am still experiencing the same